# How do i get this Notations in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xHGRy.png)
This "notations" i saw in a c# tutorial but i also experienced this "notations" in **Intellij Idea** where they were by default , so my Question is how do i set or enable that in **Visual Studio**?

I don't even know how this "notations" are actually called.

Comment: In VS you can have those from Resharper. And they are called Inline hints